# combining input task with dynamic task in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to make an input task that proceed user input and generate bunch of subtasks to run. Here is the example:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import Def.Initialize
import complete.DefaultParsers._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  val sampleInput = inputKey[Seq[String]]("sample dynamic input task")
  val sampleDynamic = taskKey[Seq[String]]("sample dynamic task")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    sampleDynamic := Def.taskDyn {
      val sources = Seq("ab", "csd", "efda")
      sources.map(sampleTaskFor _).joinWith(_.join)
    }.value,
    sampleInput := Def.inputTaskDyn {
      val sources = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      sources.map(sampleTaskFor _).joinWith(_.join)
    }.value
  )

  private def sampleTaskFor(source : String) : Initialize[Task[String]] = Def.task {
    source + " : " + source
  }
}
```

There are two samples. The first works and shows simple taskDyn with predefined input. The second is intended dynamic task with user input that refuses to compile with error that I can not interpret

```
[error] home/project/build.scala:15: Illegal dynamic reference: Def
[error]     sampleInput := Def.inputTaskDyn {
[error]                                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

How can I avoid it?

---

### Trial and error log

There I would append my question with different proposed changes that still can not solve the issue

#### replace InputTask.value with InputTask.evaluated

```
      sources.map(sampleTaskFor _).joinWith(_.join)
-   }.value
+   }.evaluated
  )
```

If I would able to define correct InputTask it should be accessed via `evaluated` method, as I've found both in documentation and in practice after trying to play with different InputTasks that compiles.

Still that would not fix the issue that sbt macro engine refuses provided `inputTaskDyn`.

---

waiting for other suggestions

Comment: I think you want `.evaluated`, not `.value`. But that doesn't make the error go away. Messed with this for a while, but I'm mystified.

Answer (score 5):

Trial and error method gave me the answer but non a single bit of understanding. Here it is:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import Def.Initialize
import complete.DefaultParsers._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  val sampleInput = inputKey[Seq[String]]("sample dynamic input task")
  val sampleDynamic = taskKey[Seq[String]]("sample dynamic task")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    sampleDynamic := Def.taskDyn {
      val sources = Seq("ab", "csd", "efda")
      sources.map(sampleTaskFor _).joinWith(_.join)
    }.value,
    sampleInput := Def.inputTaskDyn {
      val sources = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
      sampleTaskAll(sources)
    }.evaluated
  )

  private def sampleTaskFor(source : String) : Initialize[Task[String]] = Def.task {
    source + " : " + source
  }

  private def sampleTaskAll(sources : Seq[String]) : Initialize[Task[Seq[String]]] = Def.taskDyn {
    sources.map(sampleTaskFor _).joinWith(_.join)
  }
}
```

For a reason I can not comprehend you should isolate creating multitask out of sequence of single tasks in a separate method.

Comment: I don't understand either your code.  I haven't found `join()` in the documentation of `Initialize[Task[T]]`.

Comment: That question was for the 0.13.1 version and it have zero documentation for writing plugins. Documentation contained only basic usage. Some features that sbt suggests out of box was unfeasible for plugin creators. So I downloaded the source code and tried to comprehend it. Some goes smooth, some was too hard for me. I wrote the plugin and does not upgrade for newer version since I feel no energy to read the code again. And I expect that no effective documentation exists for the newer version too.

Comment: @ayvango Any update on this? I ran into this exact same issue today. Dynamic tasks and sbt's macros seem a bit flaky.

Comment: I abandoned sbt until it would have exhaustive documentation for plugin writers. Time spent on analysing source code does not worth some minor automation improvements