# Providing partial input, that comes from a setting to an input task

Tags: sbt

With this excerpt, I try to create a 2nd inputKey with some preapplied input coming from a setting:

```
val foo = inputKey[Unit]("....")
foo := { ... }
val foo2 = inputKey[Unit]("....")
foo2 := {
    foo.partialInput(" "+name.value).evaluated
}
```

But I get the `Illegal dynamic reference` error, as the arguments of `partialInput` must be constant if I use `evaluated`.

What is the best way of solving this?

Similar questions, I've read before:

- [combining input task with dynamic task in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929876/combining-input-task-with-dynamic-task-in-sbt)
- [SBT How to pass input from one inputTask to another inputTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632113/sbt-how-to-pass-input-from-one-inputtask-to-another-inputtask)
- [How to call inputTask from within another inputTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897840/how-to-call-inputtask-from-within-another-inputtask)

Using SBT 0.13.7.

[Related documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Combined+Pages.html#Input+Tasks).

The technique shown in this example taken from the SBT reference documentation doesn't work:

```
lazy val run2 = inputKey[Unit]("Runs the main class twice: " +
   "once with the project name and version as arguments"
   "and once with command line arguments preceded by hard coded values.")

// The argument string for the first run task is ' <name> <version>'
lazy val firstInput: Initialize[String] =
   Def.setting(s" ${name.value} ${version.value}")

// Make the first arguments to the second run task ' red blue'
lazy val secondInput: String = " red blue"

run2 := {
   val one = (run in Compile).fullInput(firstInput.value).evaluated
   val two = (run in Compile).partialInput(secondInput).evaluated
}
```